# What is the significance of the title of the film, "Infinity Pool"?

Tags: infinity-pool

I'm curious about the meaning behind the title of the film, [*Infinity Pool*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10365998/reference/) (2023). As far as I know, the only literal reference to an infinity pool in the film is the infinity pool that was being installed by Alban Bauer, the architect, at the Bot Vre 2 resort.

However, there seems to be a deeper, metaphorical significance to the film's title. While infinity pools appear to be limitless, they actually aren't. Is there a deeper significance to the title of *Infinity Pool*? What elements of the film serve as a metaphorical "Infinity Pool"?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that, as suggested on [the TV Tropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/InfinityPool), the "infinity pool" is a reference to the pool used for the cloning process. Just like how a pool surface reflects the person viewed in it, the cloning process creates a reflection. And much like how an infinity pool creates an illusion of no end, the cloning process creates an illusion of infinite life, since any offense can be wiped out by creating a clone to take the punishment.

I have not found official confirmation of this yet, but [this page](https://filmcolossus.com/movie-explanations/infinity-pool/title) seems to agree with the idea.

> There’s a duality to the use of “infinity pool” in the title. On the one hand, James and Em Foster are in a high-end resort in the tropical Li Tolqa. It’s the kind of fancy place you would expect to have an infinity pool, that visual illusion of the pool connecting with the ocean or sky. On the other hand, you have the Li Tolqa government’s cloning procedure. It involves standing in a tiny room while the room fills with a crimson gunk that eventually submerges you. It’s in that small space that James has his first out of body, transcendent experience, a byproduct of the conscious  portion of the cloning process.
>
> There’s some poetic connection between these two things. The standard infinity pool represents this idea of the pool extending beyond its normal confines and joining with the immensity of this other body. Then James exceeds the bounds of his own body and having this duplicate that is and isn’t him and the whole existential awakening that comes with such an experience.
>
> Dreamy interpretations aside, the simplest answer is that the pool of gunk can make innumerable clones of someone. Something we see as James, Gabi, Alban and the other reborns end up in a cycle of being arrested, cloned, and executed, just for the fun of it. That cloning process is kind of quite literally an “infinity” pool.

Comment: The underlying metaphor might be that, just as the pool creates an illusion of a long, stationary stretch of water by continually sacrificing the water at the edge, the cloning process creates the illusion of a long continuous life by continuously expending clones.